# In Microsoft Access, comparing records and updating in a form?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have 3 tables which are being used in this scenario:

1. An automatically updated Excel linked table
2. A static working table with the human approved data from the linked table.
3. An intermediate table that displays the entries that are different in the Excel link compared to the table in the database.

The goal is to essentially create a form which allows the user to look at the differences between the tables and approve changes.

There will be two listboxes to show records: one will be for the entries that table 3 found, called Changes, and one will display the entries that table 2 shares the "Name" field with (the closest thing to a primary key possible), we can call Old.

The buttons will be Add, for new entries; Ignore for faulty entries;  or Update for approving changes to existing records.

You would select one of the entries in the Changes listbox and decide what to do with it by pressing the respective button.

I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to create something along these lines in Access. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it certainly is possible. Does that answer your question?

Comment: That response most definately answers my question to the fullest! Thanks so much!

Comment: To be clearer, the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) states **You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.** Consider the following valid questions: **Excel automatically determines data types and I therefore cannot compare against an Access table.** Or **How can I make a form not connected to any specific table?**

Comment: Why do you need an intermediate table? Use a query.

Comment: How about using a hash value computed from all the fields in the Excel table, as a replacement for the primary key? The only Excel records that have to be handled are those without a matching hash value in the Excel table, and the Access records that don't have a matching hash value in the Excel table.

Comment: Did you honestly expect to find documentation on how to write the specific application that you need? Do you expect someone to write a walkthrough for every single different application that has ever been written or will ever be written?

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. As I'm sure you can tell, I'm pretty new to stack overflow, and working with databases and such, so please have some patience with the phrasing of some questions. Just trying to determine what I am really having issues on is difficult.